# How to add location information to input features?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, python

I'm working on a project to monitor the health of experimental sensors by building a ML model to classify if a given time history signal is looking as expected or if the sensor that outputed it is experiencing some kind of malfunction.

The problem is that the signal is expected to look different depending on the position of the sensor in the system in a way that maybe a given signal might be ok or not, depending on the location of the source. I'd like to know if there is a proper method to use this information of 'position' of sensor as an input feature for my neural network model.

This is my first real-world machine learning project, so I'd appreciate any kind of suggestions.